# RoR: Route for "users/2/followers" | :controller/:user_id/foo, to: ':controller#foo'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want to create the following route(s):

```
:controller/:user_id/foo, to: ':controller#foo'
```

example:

```
"users/2/followers"
```

This is what I have:

```
get 'users/:id/followers', to: 'users#followers'
```

And it works...
Questions:

- Is there a better way?
- With my solution; how can I link_to it, **what is the path**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a good solution:

```
  resources :users do 
    member do
      get :followers
    end
  end
```

The path is:

```
followers_user_path
```